# Why doesn't Visual Studio Intellisense automatically insert runat="server"?

Tags: visual-studio

For any of the common "asp:__________" controls (asp:gridview, asp:repeater, etc) I always add runat="server".  Is there any good reason that Intellisense shouldn't insert this automatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What if you really wanted to output something like `<asp:xyz>`? For example, if you wanted to generate an XML document with namespaces, you might want to use that template without any `runat="server"`, like:

```
<root xmlns="..." xmlns:asp="...">
   <asp:GridView>
       <name><%= Request["name"] %></name>
   </asp:GridView>
</root>
```

While I agree this might not be the common case, it's at least a good reason to require `runat="server"` in the first place rather than just assuming it. However, it's not always very clear where you want to specify it and where you don't want. Note that there are `HtmlControls` too. Moreover, you can define your own prefixes too. That said, I personally think VS IntelliSense system is designed not to interfere with normal typing. That is, it never works like "I think you need it most of the time. In the 1% of cases you didn't, manually remove it."

Comment: This is true, but it seems like the less common case, compared to using the asp controls for what they are.

Answer (score 1):

You could always use something like [this add-in](http://www.ardentdev.com/aspxedithelper), which inserts the runat="server" attribute for you (source code available).

Edit: the add-in has gone from it's original home, but got ported to VS2010 and now lives at http://www.rowlandoconnor.com/2010/04/16/aspx-edit-add-in-for-visual-studio-2010/

Comment: Can't seem to download this add-in for aspx editor... bummer it was good.